# Python 3: IF enter number then text code continues; if enter text or nothing than restart code: Doesn't Work

Tags: python

```
while 1:
    try:
        distance=1
        time = input("How long did it take you to reach 1 mile in seconds: ")
        f = float(time)
        speed =((distance/time)*60)*60
        print("Car",Registration_Plate,"was going at" ,speed,"Mph")
        speed_limit=60
        if speed > speed_limit:
            print("Car","'",Registration_Plate,"'"," was speeding")
        if speed ==speed_limit or speed<speed_limit:
            print("Car","'",Registration_Plate,"'"," was not speeding")
    except ValueError:
        quit
```

Comment: Is `quit` a function? If so, you need to *call* it: `quit()`. Just referencing a name on a line does not do anything.

Comment: Could you give us more details about what happens when you try and run the code? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: when I run it I write an number this shows up Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\My Documents\Controlled Assements\TEST\ERROR.py", line 6, in <module>
    speed =((distance/time)*60)*60
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: when I enter nothing the code restarts

Comment: @JakeBalebalejakey123: `time` is still a string. Did you mean to use `f`?

Comment: now when I enter a number the code still restarts

Answer (score 0):

first here is it working as you ask.

```
while 1:
    try:
        distance=1
        Registration_Plate="whatever you want"
        time = input("How long did it take you to reach 1 mile in seconds: ")
        f = float(time)
        speed =((distance/f)*60)*60
        print("Car",Registration_Plate,"was going at" ,speed,"Mph")
        speed_limit=60
        if speed > speed_limit:
            print("Car","'",Registration_Plate,"'"," was speeding")
        if speed ==speed_limit or speed<speed_limit:
            print("Car","'",Registration_Plate,"'"," was not speeding")
    except ValueError:
        quit()
```

you forgot to declare the `Registration_Plate`, next to that after the `except ValueError:` [**quit**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#quit) is a function so you use `quit()`.

NOTE:
calling quit() also closes the current instance of the python environment.
Safer would be a break or to use a variable for the while, for example:

```
exitLoop=True
while exitLoop:
    try:

        #do your code here

    except ValueError:
        exitLoop=False
```

ANOTHER NOTE:
try to explain the problem in the body, not in the title.
It makes understanding the problem a lot easier.